# How can I dynamically test text in a CSS class and then update CSS based on criteria?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm very new to this, but have a little programming background, so hopefully someone out there can parse through this with me.

I spend a LOT of time looking at Reddit for work and being able to quickly see which comments are newer than others would be super helpful. My ultimate goal is to have a color scale that will quickly guide me to the new comments. Something like Red is less than 30 minutes, Green is 30-60 minutes, and Blue is 60+ minutes or something like that.

I've been doing some research into building Chrome Extensions, and I found some similar topics, but they don't test the text in the field and update the CSS dynamically.

I would absolutely love some help walking through this. Also, if you have a partial solution, I'm open to that as well. Thank you in advance for your time and help!

**UPDATE**: I've been asked to provide code samples, but that's the real crux of my problem is I A) don't know how to even begin approaching this, and B) my web searching is not showing any results for me to play with. To be clear, I'm not asking anyone to make this extension for me. I'm looking for help identifying a CSS class area on a site, checking the text within it, and then applying a CSS addition based on results. If you can help point me to the right resources, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code.

Comment: Hi @matthew welcome to stack overflow. This seems like an interesting project, but you haven’t provided any sample code that you’ve done so far. Your essentially asking people to do this for you without examples, or at minimum you can create broad range of answers that could potentially not apply to the topic at hand or the outcome your expecting. Please see the section [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to reduce a problem.

Comment: I don't have any code other than a sample manifest.json I downloaded. I found some sites that make direct changes, but they don't run any checks on the content (age) before making the CSS updates, which are also static (one color). I literally don't know where to start here. Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just sort the comments by "Old" on the thread?

Comment: @AndrewLohr You can, but it sorts them in chunks of threaded comments. If a whole thread with multiple branches gets one new comment, it puts the whole thing at the top, but still threaded, so many older comments around it. It doesn't just show the literal new comment up top.